# Compiler error in .completePathIntoString

Tags: macos, file, compiler-errors, swift, find

I want to wrote simple code in playground which will allows me to search custom directory for "txt" and "csv" files. I have wrote this code from String Programming Guide (it's in Objective C).

This is my code:

```
// Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import Cocoa

var str = "Hello, playground"

var partialPath : NSString = "~/aaa/"
var longestCompletition : NSString
var outputArray : NSArray
var filterTypes = ["txt", "csv"]

var allMatches = [partialPath .completePathIntoString(longestCompletition, caseSensitive: 0, matchesIntoArray: outputArray, filterTypes: filterTypes)]

println(outputArray)
```

And this is code from that guide:

```
NSString *partialPath = @"~/Demo/r";
NSString *longestCompletion;
NSArray *outputArray;
NSArray *filterTypes = @[@"txt", @"rtf"];

unsigned textMatches = [partialPath completePathIntoString:&outputName
caseSensitive:NO
matchesIntoArray:&outputArray
filterTypes:filterTypes];
```

I get error in Output:

> NSString is not convertible to AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer

Where I made mistake?

Comment: What's wrong with your code? Any error? compilation fails? wrong output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This makes the compiler pass:

```
var str = "Hello, playground"

var partialPath : NSString = "~/aaa/"
var longestCompletition : NSString?
var outputArray : NSArray? = []
var filterTypes = ["txt", "csv"]

var allMatches = partialPath.completePathIntoString(&longestCompletition, caseSensitive: false, matchesIntoArray: &outputArray, filterTypes: filterTypes)

println(outputArray)
```

but I can't say anything about the correctness of what it is supposed to do - I leave that to you.

Comment: anyway outputArray have value nil... in directory aaa i have 3 files csv, aaa.csv and aaa.txt

Comment: try initializing the array `var outputArray : NSArray? = []`

Comment: i get Optional(<__NSArray| 0x7fc321503a60>(/n/n)/n) any ideas?

Comment: No. Have you tried the objc code to see if you have any different result? Just to be sure whether it's an incorrect usage of the API or a swift related problem

Comment: Yeah I know - I meant to try it in an obj-c project

Comment: how to try it in playground? its impossible.

Comment: I said a project, not playground

Comment: i leave this project beacuse there was some changes in app concept but thanks for help.